# Assume that $f\in C^2(\Bbb R^n,\Bbb R^n)$, for $x\in \Bbb R^n, \det Df(x)\ne 0$, when $|x|\to +∞,|f(x)|\to +∞$. Prove that $f(\Bbb R^n)=\Bbb R^n$.

Tags: calculus, analysis

> Assuming that $f\in C^2(\Bbb R^n,\Bbb R^n)$, for any $x$ belong to $\Bbb R^n, \det Df(x)\ne 0$, (its value is never zero) and when $|x|\to +\infty,|f(x)|\to +\infty$.
> Try to prove that: $f(\Bbb R^n)=\Bbb R^n$.
>
>  [Original Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiAo7.jpg)

My main difficulties are that I don't know how it connects with the extreme value , what's the effect of $f$ is $C^2$, and that how to assert that vector $f$ covers the whole space $\Bbb R^n$ from the condition of $|f(x)|\to +\infty$.

Supplement: I am a Chinese student in `Grade 1` of university who is taking a course called mathematical analysis or calculus. I have at least studied differential calculus of functions of several variables. I'm studying the extremum of functions of several variables now .

I already know that the range of $f$ is an ‘open area', so the only question is how to prove that $f$ is large enough to cover $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: This could be a great question.  I'll embed the image for you, but could you say more about the last paragraph?  E.g., It would help to know your level in math, and the name of the class you're taking, or author of the text/exercise, because we can then better gauge how to help you the most.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: The basic idea is that $f$ can fail to cover all of $\Bbb R^n$ in two ways. One is that it is "too feeble" to make it out to $\infty$, but the limit condition says this isn't the case here. The other is that $f$ avoids some point in its interior. But the only way to do this is to turn away from that point, which would require $Df$ to be singular somewhere. This is what you need to prove.

Comment: Thank you , but I am still confused  about the first  condition that f is "too feeble" to make it out to ∞.  The limit condition only says the length of vector f stretches to +∞, but how to prove that f could be large enough in all directions （as a vector）?

Answer (score 1):

Since you already know that $f(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is open it is sufficient to show that $f(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is closed too (then $f(\mathbb{R}^n)=\mathbb{R}^n$). So let $(y_n)$ be a convergent sequence in $f(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with limit $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, say, and let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(x_n)=y_n$ $(n \in \mathbb{N})$. Now $(x_n)$ is bounded: otherwise it has a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ with $\|x_{n_k}\| \to \infty$, hence $\|y_{n_k}\|=\|f(x_{n_k})\| \to \infty$, a contradiction. Thus $(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ with limit $a$, say, and we get $f(a)=b$. Thus $b \in  f(\mathbb{R}^n)$.